# Loading Static Resource into Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, static-resources

I am trying to access the test.png file from my static resource into my css of a aura component.

Working CSS:

```
background:url('/resource/158765027200/test');  
//resource path achieved using {!$Resource.test} in .cmp
```

Non-Working CSS:

```
background:url('/resource/test');
```

Issue with the working CSS is that the static resource code is dynamic in nature and hence will vary from one salesforce instance to another, making this code non-ideal for deployment to other instances of salesforce.

Can anyone help me with this issue or any resolution?

Comment: Have you tried what is described in the documentation? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error? We need more info. It should work, according to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/143630/2984).

Comment: Hi Florian, I have referred the documentation and using <img src="{!$Resource.generic_profile_svg}"/> loads the image at the background as it has to be used in .cmp file AND not sure how I can use  var profUrl = $A.get('$Resource.yourGraphics') + '/images/avatar1.jpg'; in CSS. The Idea is to have the .png file loaded only in .CSS.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, not sure why using an extra "<div></div>" its working, however using below code its not working, that is strange for me.
<div class="loading" style="height: 166px;width: 189px;"> </div>