Refer static resource in css of lightning component in Managed Packages
I have a CSS with a class like this:
  .c-rating__item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 24px;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 24px;
            flex: 0 0 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url("/resource/fivestar/stars.svg");
    background-position: 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

And it's working fine. The problem is when I generate the package and install it in a different Org, I get a 404 error:
Request URL:
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resource/fivestar/stars.svg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Any idea how I can solve this?

Verify that the stars.svg file is included in the static resources of your package.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000N58EtUAJ/lwc-use-static-resource-image-in-css-in-lightning-web-component



https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143630/refer-static-resource-in-css-of-lightning-component?rq=1


This question is similar to: LWC: How to use static Resource Image in CSS in Lightning Web Component?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Obviously, I have verified the svg is included. If you read my comment, It works fine in my scratch org. It breaks when you generate a managed package with a namespace.
It not the same question than you suggested. My problem is when I generate a managed package with a namespace.

I cannot use the post that you refer because the rules are clear:
_But avoid …
Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience._

Solved: I just need to add the namespace in the static resource reference:
 background: url("/resource/MyNamespace__fivestar/stars.svg");
